# Unexpected '<' encountered?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to convert my timelines to actionscript. Adobe Flash CS5 allows me to select my tween on my timeline, and hit a "Copy motion to Actionscript 3". I hit the button, then paste the code. I followed this tutorial perfectly

http://layersmagazine.com/animation-to-code-flash.html

But every time I run I get a lot of errors complaining about my ActionScript that was generated for me. Saying things like

Scene=Scene 1, layer=Layer 13, frame=1, Line 2   Unexpected '<' encountered

Scene=Scene 1, layer=Layer 13, frame=1, Line 4   Operator '>' must be followed by an operand

etc

My Actionscript looks just like the one from the tutorial, any buddy have any idea why its not working?

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of your code so we can see it?

Comment: I figured it out... *sigh* simple error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The project I had open was targeting Actionscript 2, I just had to change it to target 3.